# ReferenceError: element is not defined - cordova-plugin-googlemaps

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, google-maps-api-3, cordova-plugins

I'm working on an Ionic 3 project and for map related functionality, I chose [Google Maps](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native-google-maps/blob/master/documents/README.md) plugin suggested by Ionic Team. The Google Maps Ionic plugin is basically a wrapper around [cordova-plugin-googlemaps](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps). I've followed the steps mentioned in this [presentation](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1zlkmoSY4AzDJc_P4IqWLnzct41IqHyzGkLeyhlAxMDE/edit#slide=id.p).

I'm not able to show map in element with id `map_canvas`, which is placed in one of page html. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { GoogleMaps, GoogleMap, Marker } from '@ionic-native/google-maps';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-step-two',
  templateUrl: 'step-two.html',
})
export class StepTwoPage {

  private stepTwoForm: FormGroup;
  private map: GoogleMap;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.stepTwoForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      prename: ['', Validators.required],
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      mobile: ['', Validators.required],
      yearLiving: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    // Create a map after the view is ready 
    // and the native platform is ready.
    this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap() {
    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas'); // <--- Problematic statement
  }

  goToStepThree() {

  }

}
```

And here's page html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Step - 2</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <progress-bar [stepCount]="5" [currentStep]="2"></progress-bar>

  <ion-card class="step-body-card">
    <ion-card-header>
      <h1 text-center class="card-title">Persona</h1>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      <form [formGroup]="stepTwoForm" (ngSubmit)="goToStepThree()">
        <ion-grid>
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-12 col-sm>
              <ion-item>
                <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Prename" formControlName="prename"></ion-input>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-12 col-sm>
              <ion-item>
                <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Name" formControlName="name"></ion-input>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-12 col-sm>
              <ion-item>
                <ion-input type="email" placeholder="Email" formControlName="email"></ion-input>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-12 col-sm>
              <ion-item>
                <ion-input type="tel" placeholder="Mobile" formControlName="mobile"></ion-input>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-12 col-sm>
              <ion-item>
                <ion-input type="number" min="0" placeholder="Year of living" formControlName="yearLiving"></ion-input>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-12 col-sm>

            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
        <button margin-top ion-button type="submit" [disabled]="!stepTwoForm.valid">Continue</button>
      </form>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

I tried running in Android and it gives an error, without anyhting being shown on `map_canvas` element. The error is produced by cordova:

```
Error in Success callbackId: CordovaGoogleMaps1188158820 : ReferenceError: element is not defined
```

And here's stack-trace from console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: element is not defined
    at Map.<anonymous> (:8100/plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/CordovaGoogleMaps.js:645)
    at Map.trigger (:8100/plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/BaseClass.js:68)
    at Map.set (:8100/plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/BaseClass.js:35)
    at Map.getMap (:8100/plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/Map.js:152)
    at :8100/plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/CordovaGoogleMaps.js:881
    at Object.callbackFromNative (cordova.js:291)
    at <anonymous>:1:9
```

I can confirm that this error is produced by statement while initializing or creating map, pointed out as Problematic statement in page.ts. I'm unable to get the underlying problem for this error.

Please help me troubleshooting the problem and suggest fix.

**EDIT**
After debugging I found out that the error only occurs if the `map_canvas` element (div) is inside the `form`, if I take it out of the `form` tag, it works as expected and map shows.

Maybe this is a bug or something is wrong with `FormBuilder`. I need to show Google Map inside form, so please help me fixing this odd behavior of Google Map plugin. Edited question which includes full form for reference now and simplified map creation logic.

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/blob/master/v2.0.0/ReleaseNotes/ionic-googlemaps-4.4.0/README.md) help?

Comment: @ChrisG I'm already using v4.4.0 way of creating a map, and that's problematic statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

After building shared project, I can not reproduce the error [image]

The problem has been gone at least v2.3.8

Comment: There's no difference between both of them, as the `create` method accepts both forms, `HTMLElement` or an element's identifier string. I tried with your suggestion, but no luck. BTW, it should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: wow, really bad comment. I'm the author of cordova-plugin-googlemaps. Well, I recommend you use another maps plugin.

Comment: I originally had used the way you described but it didn't work. I've edited the question with more debugging info. I believe as a plugin author you can definitely help with that debug info and also remember that I'm using [`Google Maps`](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native-google-maps/blob/master/documents/README.md) wrapper provided by Ionic team for this maps plugin.

Comment: I can't decide what the problem is, because provided information is too less. Please share your project files on GitHub. (Creating a reproducible project is fine)

Comment: Here's GitHub public repo for this project: https://github.com/malviyaritesh/five-steps. Don't expect everything to work or completed as this project is ongoing. Thanks for your help. The problem lies in `StepTwoPage`.

Comment: Although in the same project I'm still getting the error, but after transferring my files to new fresh project, seems like the error is gone.